# Significant performance drop when instantiating specific usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datacontext

I am developing a WPF app from 2 locations, one has a beefy PC on windows 10, the other has a much older PC with worse hardware, running Windows 7.

on the windows 10 PC, I never notice a problem, this is only reproducible on windows 7 machine.

In my Window, I have a ContentControl which is bound to a UserControl property in the window's viewmodel.

I can show different usercontrols there, and most behave fine. I have 2 however, which when I attempt to load them, they take literally 3-5 seconds, during which the UI thread hangs.

They don't have much going on in xaml, I have more complex stuff in xaml in other controls so I don't think the problem lies there.

The one thing these 2 controls are doing differently, which other controls which don't have this issue aren't doing is in the constructor for the usercontrol in the .xaml.cs file, they set their datacontext.

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new CreateGroupPanelViewModel();
```

The contructor for the viewmodel, just sets some properties to values. Mainly some string to string.Empty, instantiates 2 ObservableCollections, sets a bool to true and sets a string to "Create Game".

The first time I open this control, I have the problem but the second time it poses no delay at all. Also, if I run the program for a minute or so and THEN try to open it for the first time it will also be fine.

I cannot understand why instantiating this usercontrol would create such a massive performance hit, or why it would act so differently on the 2 different machines.

**EDIT**
The slowdown occurs within the InitializeComponent(); of the usercontrol.

Here is the XAML of such a control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CasinoDB.UserControls.ModifyPanels.UCModifyGamePanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CasinoDB.UserControls.ModifyPanels"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CasinoDB.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Name:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="150" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="RTP:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding RTP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="50" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Variance:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Variance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="150" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Lines:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Lines, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="100" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Min Bet:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MinBet, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="50" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Max Win:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MaxWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="75" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Vendor:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Vendor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" MinWidth="150" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="Notes:" Margin="5" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Notes}" Margin="5" Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Height="75" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
            </StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Content="Create Another" IsChecked="{Binding CreateAnother}" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding ShowCreateAnother, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                <Button Content="SAVE" Command="{Binding Save}" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource ConfirmButton}" />
                <Button Content="CLOSE" Command="{Binding Close}" Margin="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Are you doing any binding?

Comment: Trace your ViewModel constructor, may be  something is being lazy loaded and blocking your UI thread!

Comment: Sorry for delay - Have been away from affected machine til today.
The performance drop comes from the `InitializeComponent();` in the user controls constructor - the VM constructor is near instant. And yes, there are bindings within the UC, but not an awful lot, or any complexity etc (no converters used for example).

Comment: InitializeComponent() is what loads the XAML and thus creates all the controls at runtime. Are you doing something in the XAML that has to allocate any major resources or attempting to access something on the network? Can you show us the XAML you are using?

Comment: @JeffR.I edited original post to include the XAML of one of the user controls causing this slow down. Other than the bindings to VM, the only other things referenced are a static resource of ConfirmButton and a converter BooleanToVisibilityConverter, both of which I use in other controls without issue

Comment: you are right, it doesn't look too complex so you should look into if any get for any of those bound properties is doing something crazy. Or if you have something running in background thread or task that is taking longer than it should.

Comment: @JeffR.There's nothing special in the getters of any of the bindings. The vart majority are just straight up properties returning their backing field, Save and Close are ICommand Properties which instantiate the backing field if its null (which I use a lot elsewhere without problem), the ConfirmButton static resource is just a small bit of XAML to make a buttons font bold, make the button IsDefault=true, and make its background a little lighter. BooleanToVisibilityConverter does what it says it does, and I have used that plenty of times also without problem.I dont know what could be causing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after attempting to isolate the issue, I finally found my problem. It lies in `SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"` on TextBoxes. I found this by commenting out large sections, testing performance, then uncommenting small amounts until it was acting slow on the machine it acts slow on.

After figuring this was the cause, I found a similar post on SO with information relating to a registry entry being filled up with dictionairies. I don't appear to have an entry in that location in the registry, so maybe my problem was similar, but that it was looking and couldn't find anything at all.

Anyway, I can live without spellcheck in those fields, I'll just remove it.